# How does one feed non-edge dyad attributes into a network object in R?

Tags: r, network-programming

I'm trying to work with objects of the class ``network'' (the network package). I noticed that edgelist easily handles dyadic attributes, but it is unclear how to give R information about dyadic attributes for those dyads for which an edge does not exist. Obviously ignoring this data will bias my coefficients in further statistical analysis. Has anyone encountered this problem and have any advice?

Example: Say I have a network (1,...,5). An edgelist matrix, I think, would have columns of the node IDs, along with edge covariates (here, suppose unemployment rate of countries or something, with an edge meaning whether they have a treaty)

myedgelist:

1 3 .08

2 4 .06

2 5 .1

3 5 .04

I could then do some stats on this, and throw in the (edit:) unemployment covariate. But I dont see a way to throw in the trade data for non-edge dyads (1 and 2, for instance).

UPDATE: The edgelist is what's connected. The network object would be defined as

object <- network(myedgelist,matrix.type = "edgelist", directed=F)

Comment: Can you post a simple example of your graph data (perhaps a few nodes) and how you created it? It is much easier to work with a concrete example than an abstract concept.

Comment: Just made a bunch of edits. sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Ok, but `network(1,...,5)` is not valid R code. How are you initializing this network. You are supplying a matrix indicating what's connected, correct?

Comment: Just answered your question above.

Comment: That's a bit confusing because unemployment would a property of the vertex, it's not pair specific. You can really only store attributes on the network as a whole, an edge, or on a vertex. If you have different dyadic properties that you want to track, you will need different networks with edges. But it's an edge that connects two vertices; if they have no connection, they can't share information.

Comment: Unemployment was a bad example. I am referring to some dyadic property (dyad trade in trillions?). What do you mean by "you will need different networks with edges"

Comment: It you have different sets of connection between objects, I meant you would actually create multiple network objects each with different edgelists. I'm not sure exactly how you're doing your "analysis". But you could also also create one network where all "related" vertices have an edge if they have a dyadic attribute. Then things like "has treaty" can be a 0/1 valued edge attribute and the trade in trillions can be a different attribute on that same edge.

Comment: Thanks. I'll call that the best answer possible. I think that network objects can't deal with non-edge dyadic data, simply. This requires me to move on to an alternative statistical approach, which I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

It you have different sets of connection between objects, I meant you would actually create multiple network objects each with different edgelists. I'm not sure exactly how you're doing your "analysis". But you could also also create one network where all "related" vertices have an edge if they have a dyadic attribute. Then things like "has treaty" can be a 0/1 valued edge attribute and the trade in trillions can be a different attribute on that same edge. –  MrFlick Jun 1 at 18:27

Answer (score 0):

Edge attributes/coviariates can only be attached to an edge in the network.  You could either implement this using multiple networks as user3693016, or as a single "multiplex" network (network with multiple types of edges). The off which option is better will depend on what you are trying to do with the network.